# What is the difference between vanilla Minecraft and FTB?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, terminology

What is the difference between vanilla and FTB Minecraft?  I was playing Minecraft and my brother asked if it was vanilla or FTB and I said I didn't know.  So now I am asking this site to see what the answer is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vanilla means a version of Minecraft without mods. Mods are modified .jar files that often change how you play. Unless you installed a mod, you have this version of Minecraft right now.

FTB refers to "Feed the Beast," and is a collection of popular mods.

There is some debate over whether 3rd party Minecraft-external programs counts as "vanilla" (such as MCEdit), but generally it is decided that it DOES still count as vanilla.

Answer (score 7):

- *Vanilla* refers to normal Minecraft without any modifications (also called mods). You probably have this version of Minecraft right now if you don't know what mods are or what `Minecraft.jar` is.
- *FTB* is Minecraft executed through [this](http://feed-the-beast.com) program. FTB itself stands for **F**eed **T**he **B**east. It uses a new *launcher*, which is the thing you use to start Minecraft, to automatically add mods to Minecraft.

Answer (score 4):

FTB stands for Feed the Beast. Feed the Beast is a collection of popular 3rd party Minecraft mods which add a lot of features- it's most well known for adding more industrial blocks such as automatic drills and generators to power them.

For more information on Feed the Beast or to download it, visit their website: http://feed-the-beast.com/

Vanilla refers to an unmodded version of Minecraft. This is what you are playing at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla means the original Minecraft the one you download from https://minecraft.net/ and contains no mods (modifications).

FTB is an acronym for Feed The Beast which has 3rd party mod packs.

This may mean:
   1. You have an older version of Minecraft
   2. You might not be able to connect to vanilla minecraft servers because you have a    outdated version of Minecraft, and might be kicked from the server for cheating unless the server was specified for the modpack.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla is the version of minecraft if you don't have mods. FTB is a thing that stands for feed the beast and has 3rd party mod packs.